# How to call alertdialog from another file? using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how do I call the alert dialog from another dart file, when the user clicks the button in ***addstudents.dart***, I want to make the alert dialog in another file just in case it can be reused? In my addstudents.dart i have this Container, please see the code below, thanks.

addstudents.dart

```
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              width: (globals.screenWidth * 0.48),
              height: (globals.screenHeight * 0.10),
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              child: RaisedButton(
                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  // calling another file dart
                },
                color: Colors.green,
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                      text: "Confirmed!",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: "Nunito",
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: globals.fontsize_19)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

this is my alertdialog.dart

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Flutter'),
          ),
          body: MyLayout()),
    );
  }
}
class MyLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Show alert'),
        onPressed: () {
          showAlertDialog(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {

  Widget okButton = FlatButton(
    child: Text("OK"),
    onPressed: () {},
  );
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("My title"),
    content: Text("This is my message."),
    actions: [
      okButton,
    ],
  );
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno if this is the best practice but here's what I'm doing

```
 class Alerts {
  static showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    Widget okButton = FlatButton(
      child: Text("OK"),
      onPressed: () {},
    );

    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text("My title"),
      content: Text("This is my message."),
      actions: [
        okButton,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

> I call them using **Alerts.showAlertDialog(context)**;

Comment: where this code come from? from `alertdialog.dart`? how do i call this code in `addstudents.dart` ?

Comment: isn't your goal for your alert dialog to be reused? in other widgets

Comment: exactly!! what should i do?

Comment: do i have to create another dart file ?

Comment: nicee then try this code :D, create another dart file and post the code above thennn call the function in your button :)

Comment: then how do i call the `class Alert`? like this `Alerts();`?

Comment: U can use just Alerts.showAlertDialog(context) in your button since its a static function

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Dean is the simplest I have seen for a beginner like me and the most understandable. I edited Dean's code with a variable title and message, just in case some other newbie like me needs help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Alerts{
  static showSimpleAlert(BuildContext context, title, message) {
    Widget okButton = TextButton(
      child: Text("OK"),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
    );

    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text(title),
      content: Text(message),
      actions: [
        okButton,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then to call it,

```
 Alerts.showSimpleAlert(context, "Sign-in Failed", "Please check your credentials used");
```